# Vim plugin for adding external links

Tags: vim, markdown

Now, this may be something obvious and already solved and known to everyone, but I just thought of it, so have mercy ...

Is there a Vim plugin for (when writing markdown texts) that enables you to insert links in a way that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> in here (StackOverflow) does it. Or something similar to it.

For example, I write in a link, http://www.google.com, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>, and it moves that link to the bottom of the page replacing it with [description][28] where 28 is the current (increase by one from last) identifier.

Anyone? Anything similar?

Comment: Ask on [vim_use](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_use), which is where the pros hang out.

Answer (score 6):

I use a custom macro to insert links from the system clipboard (Tested with Vim 7.3 on OS X and Windows, should work with Linux, too) and use [formd](http://drbunsen.github.com/formd/) to convert the resulting inline-style links to reference-style when I see fit.

I got these macros in my `.vimrc`:

```
" Create a Markdown-link structure for the current word or visual selection with
" leader 3. Paste in the URL later. Or use leader 4 to insert the current
" system clipboard as an URL.
nnoremap <Leader>3 ciw[<C-r>"]()<Esc>
vnoremap <Leader>3 c[<C-r>"]()<Esc>
nnoremap <Leader>4 ciw[<C-r>"](<Esc>"*pli)<Esc>
vnoremap <Leader>4 c[<C-r>"](<Esc>"*pli)<Esc>
```

And use these to invoke `formd` which lives in my `~/bin/` folder:

```
" Use formd to transfer markdown from inline to reference links and vice versa
" see: http://drbunsen.github.com/formd/
nmap <leader>fr :%! ~/bin/formd -r<CR>
nmap <leader>fi :%! ~/bin/formd -i<CR>
```

So, I just copy the needed link, navigate to the word (or use visual mode to select more words) to turn into a link and hit `,4`. If I know I'll link a word or selection but don't have the URL yet, I hit `,3` and the macro inserts the needed parentheses empty.

Hitting `,fr` produces the reference-style. If needed, `,fi` returns to inline-style links.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have an exact matching solution, but my [vim-googurl](https://github.com/roma1n/vim-googurl) plugin does part of the job.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not the exact workflow you described [this plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=431) seems like it is designed for making footnotes easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

`:help autocmd` can be used to list the possible options.

it may not do exactly what you asking for but you can change it to your needs.

```
autocmd Filetype markdown,rmd noremap ,1 i[][]<Esc>bplla1<esc>m1Go[1]:<Space><esc>p'1f1wa<Space>
autocmd Filetype markdown,rmd noremap ,2 i[][]<Esc>bplla2<esc>m2Go[2]:<Space><esc>p'2f2wa<Space>
```

where `1` may be the first link and `2` the second...

put your link into the primary selection.
position your cursor in normal mode and hit `,1` to begin.

Answer (score 0):

In regard to Dennis Wegners answer and his `.vimrc` entry for `<leader>4` this worked for me:

```
nnoremap <leader>4 ciw[<C-r>"](<Esc>"*pa)<Esc><CR>
vnoremap <leader>4 c[<C-r>"](<Esc>"*pa)<Esc><CR>
```

`"*pil` resulted in not writing the closing `)` but with `"*pa` it works.