# Generate inline rather than list-style footnotes in Pandoc Markdown output?

Tags: regex, markdown, pandoc, footnotes

When converting from some format (say, HTML or Docx) to Markdown in Pandoc, is it possible to render all footnotes in the inline style ("this is the main text^[this is a footnote]") rather than as numbered references with a corresponding list at the end of the document? I want to work on my Markdown documents (converted from a Docx of my thesis) as master texts, but now if I add a new footnote it messes up the numbering.

Alternatively, is there another convenient way (i.e. not Pandoc) that this could be done? Cutting text in one part of a file and adding corresponding text in another part seems a bit beyond a simple regex.

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: I've just hacked up [an extremely simple Python script](https://github.com/ltrgoddard/inliner/blob/master/inliner.py) to do this, in case anyone else has the same issue.

Comment: Hmm, I was going to say that your desired output is not even a valid footnote in Markdown, but then I checked and Pandoc actually accepts that as a footnote. As Pandoc is the **only** Markdown implementation that I am aware of which accepts that syntax, I would avoid it if at all possible. It seems like a bad design decision to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandoc's Markdown syntax is quite flexible about [footnotes](http://pandoc.org/README.html#footnotes):

> The footnotes themselves need not be placed at the end of the document. They may appear anywhere except inside other block elements (lists, block quotes, tables, etc.).

Like:

```
Here is a footnote reference[^1] and some more text.

[^1]: Here is the footnote.

Here's the next paragraph.
```

However, the Markdown Writer (the module that generates markdown files, as opposed to reading them) currently simply [places all of them at the end](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Markdown.hs#L191) of the document. But this could be implemented behind a flag, similar to the `--reference-links` flag. Feel free to submit an issue or pull request!

Answer (score 0):

Inline footnotes and references are quite nice for writing and editing markdown documents, but cumbersome for reading them.

I used [ltrgoddard's inliner](https://github.com/ltrgoddard/inliner) with success to process several files that I use with pandoc and latexmk to produce PDF. `inliner` works well for transforming end-style references to inline style references in an already-written document.

Cross references to other questions and clues for posterity:

[Convert markdown links from inline to reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30917399/convert-markdown-links-from-inline-to-reference)

[Vim plugin for adding external links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985360/vim-plugin-for-adding-external-links/14284350#14284350)

Also see http://drbunsen.github.io/formd/
and https://instant-thinking.de/2014/02/20/markdown-footnotes-with-vim/ for more info re: formd, which should work for converting inline references end-style references, and vice-versa.

**Note that `formd` works on URLs and ignores footnotes, so this may be seen as a similar project (with different goals) but not an alternative.**